# "Can not create Stax reader for the Source passed" error

Tags: sax, stax

I have the following code:

```
public Object unmarshal(Source source, MimeContainer mimeContainer) throws XmlMappingException {
    AttachmentUnmarshaller au = null;
    if (this.mtomEnabled && mimeContainer != null) {
        au = new MISMarshaller.MISAttachmentUnmarshaller(mimeContainer);
    }

    if (source instanceof SAXSource && ((SAXSource)source).getXMLReader() != null) {
        try {
            XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            return this.context.unmarshal(au, factory.createXMLStreamReader(source));
        } catch (Exception var5) {
            throw new UnmarshallingFailureException(var5.getMessage(), var5);
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Only StAX is supported for MIS marshaller.  Use AXIOM message factory.");
    }
}
```

On this line, I get an exception:

```
            return this.context.unmarshal(au, factory.createXMLStreamReader(source));
```

Here is the exception:

> javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Can not create Stax reader for
>   the Source passed -- neither reader, input stream nor system id was
>   accessible; can not use other types of sources (like embedded SAX
>   streams)

At run-time, `source` is an instance of `StaxSource`.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like since Spring 3.0, you can use the `StaxUtils(org.springframework.util.xml.StaxUtils)` class in favor of the deprecated `StaxResult` class directly.  I found some examples, and you could do something like this for the `marshal` method:

```
public void marshal(Object graph, Result result, MimeContainer mimeContainer) throws XmlMappingException {
    try {
        AttachmentMarshaller am = null;
        if (this.mtomEnabled && mimeContainer != null) {
            am = new MISMarshaller.MISAttachmentMarshaller(mimeContainer);
        }
        if (StaxUtils.isStaxResult(result) && StaxUtils.getXMLStreamWriter(result) != null) {
            this.context.marshal(graph, am, StaxUtils.getXMLStreamWriter(result));
        } else {
            if (!(result instanceof SAXResult) || ((SAXResult)result).getHandler() == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Only StAX or SAX is supported for MIS marshaller.  Use AXIOM message factory.");
            }
            this.context.marshal(graph, am, (SAXResult)result);
        }
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        throw new MarshallingFailureException(var5.getMessage(), var5);
    }
}
```

versus the old method where it used to be:

```
public void marshal(Object graph, Result result, MimeContainer mimeContainer) throws XmlMappingException {
    try {
        AttachmentMarshaller am = null;
        if (this.mtomEnabled && mimeContainer != null) {
            am = new MISMarshaller.MISAttachmentMarshaller(mimeContainer);
        }
        if (result instanceof StaxResult && ((StaxResult)result).getXMLStreamWriter() != null) {
            this.context.marshal(graph, am, ((StaxResult)result).getXMLStreamWriter());
        } else {
            if (!(result instanceof SAXResult) || ((SAXResult)result).getHandler() == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Only StAX or SAX is supported for MIS marshaller.  Use AXIOM message factory.");
            }
            this.context.marshal(graph, am, (SAXResult)result);
        }
    } catch (Exception var5) {
        throw new MarshallingFailureException(var5.getMessage(), var5);
    }
}
```